Enable Routing in React static web app after deployment
I have a static web app (React/Typescript) with the following routes/pages:
index.ts
ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="" element={<App />}>
              <Route path="/" element={<JobsPage />} />
              <Route path="/JobDetails" element={<JobDetails />} />
              <Route path="/OwnerPage" element={<OwnerPage />} />
              <Route path="/AdminConfig" element={<AdminConfig />} />
              <Route path="/ManageMembership" element={<ManageMembership />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

On running locally, I can go to these pages directly. For example, "localhost:3000/ManageMembership" takes me to ManageMembership page. After deployment, "abc.com/ManageMembership" is showing "Not Found". It's not redirecting to ManageMembership page. But, if I click a button on the UI, I see the URL set to abc.com/ManageMembership. If I try to access this URL directly instead via clicking button, it shows "Not Found". What am I missing and how do I fix this?

If it's a GET request and an app route then serve the index.html. Or you can say if it's a GET request and not a file asset then do it (but that requires an I/O lookup). How to do that depends on how to config your server (I just noticed you added azure tag).

Hosting service/Server needs to be setup/configured to serve the root index.html file and assets for all page requests into the app. Check these deployments docs and verify your Azure setup.

@user989988 please provide your github repo if possible.

@user989988 Have you added staticwebapp.config.json file in your project?

I created a sample React.js application, deployed it to Azure Static Web Apps, and successfully redirected to the specific route.

To fix the page not founderror , I've added a staticwebapp.config.json file in the root directory of the project.
It works fine locally, but in production, a staticwebapp.config.json file is required to handle routes.
It allows you to configure routing, authentication, and authorization for your apps on Azure.

Please add the below staticwebapp.config.json file in your project directory.
{
"routes": [
{
"route": "/api/*",
"allowedRoles": ["anonymous", "authenticated"]
},
{
"route": "/",
"serve": "/index.html",
"statusCode": 200
},
{
"route": "/JobsPage",
"serve": "/index.html",
"statusCode": 200
},
{
"route": "/ManageMembership",
"serve": "/index.html",
"statusCode": 200
},
{
"route": "/JobDetails",
"serve": "/index.html",
"statusCode": 200
},
{
"route": "/OwnerPage",
"serve": "/index.html",
"statusCode": 200
},
{
"route": "/AdminConfig",
"serve": "/index.html",
"statusCode": 200
}
],
"navigationFallback": {
"rewrite": "/index.html",
"exclude": ["/api/*"]
}
}

My index.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import JobsPage from './pages/JobsPage';
import ManageMembership from './pages/ManageMembership';
import JobDetails from './pages/JobDetails';
import OwnerPage from './pages/OwnerPage';
import AdminConfig from './pages/AdminConfig';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>   
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="JobsPage" element={<JobsPage />} />
        <Route path="ManageMembership" element={<ManageMembership />} />
        <Route path="JobDetails" element={<JobDetails />} />
        <Route path="OwnerPage" element={<OwnerPage />} />
        <Route path="AdminConfig" element={<AdminConfig />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

My index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<meta  charset="utf-8"  />
<link  rel="icon"  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"  />
<meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"  />
<meta  name="theme-color"  content="#000000"  />
<meta
name="description"
content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
<link  rel="apple-touch-icon"  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png"  />
<link  rel="manifest"  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json"  />
<title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div  id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>

I've successfully deployed the application to Azure static web app via Github actions.

Local output:

Output after deployment:


Thank you! Where do I add this file? Also, can I set a  instead of html in serve? Can you please share your sample project code?

@user989988 add staticwebapp.config.file in root directory of your project.

In the staticwebapp.config.json file, you can’t directly serve a React component (like ) because Azure only serves static files. However, by mapping routes like ManageMembership to index.html, React will handle the routing and render the correct component based on the routes you’ve defined in your app.

And also, in your code you've included / in the routes like this
<Route path="/ManageMembership" element={<ManageMembership />} />
please remove / and change them to like this
<Route path="ManageMembership" element={<ManageMembership />} />
respectively

I've added my index.tsx file to the solution. Please check it.

Can you share your index.html? Is it possible to specify React component within html? Can you explain your example with multiple html files instead of a single index.html? Please let me know.

React components like <ManageMembership /> are written in JavaScript, so they can't be directly added to an HTML file. Instead, React uses its routing system to load and display these components within the app.

We use a single index.html to keep the app simple and efficient. Having multiple HTML files would break how a React app works. Instead, we point all routes to index.html in the staticwebapp.config.json so React can manage the navigation smoothly.

Please share your index.html file.and is it possible to navigate to a page for example  from index.html?

@user989988 Added my index.html file in solution please check, regarding specifying react component within html i'll try and let you know.

@user989988 Is your issue resolved?

In App.js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage/MainPage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './components/RegisterPage/RegisterPage';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import DetailsPage from './components/DetailsPage/DetailsPage';
import SearchPage from './components/SearchPage/SearchPage';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';

function App() {
  return (
        <>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
          <Route path="/app" element={<MainPage />} />
          <Route path="/app/login" element={<LoginPage/>} />
          <Route path="/app/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
          <Route path="/app/product/:productId" element={<DetailsPage/>} />
          <Route path="/app/search" element={<SearchPage/>} />
          <Route path="/app/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
        </Routes>
        </>
  );
}
export default App;

This is simple sample. I use this code, display in localhost:3000. I think importing route is very important , you listen and do like this.

OP says "On running locally, I can go to these pages directly." – that means they've imported their components just fine.
